# php script to generate direct links of google drive files skipping virus scan warning?

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api

php script to generate direct links of publicly shared google drive files skipping virus scan warning
I founded many similar scrips doing so like

https://links-safety.com/drive/

https://linkstaker.com/drive/

they are exactly similar 
what they reqire is only ID eg. 1C25uoL6nIqqNhex3wm8VwODsO2q2pXBt

https://links-safety.com/drive/i0yp6ymfgniv8lj1x6y8d7rj1

https://linkstaker.com/drive/download.php?id=86bc9a7559123e8982cf

they are not using api as the file url is just same as we click on download anyway button on virus scan page

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to calculate the confirm code (here: CfLW), you can hotlink the file like this:
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=CfLW&id=1C25uoL6nIqqNhex3wm8VwODsO2q2pXBt

Otherwise you can get the hotlink by first downloading the warning page and looking for the hotlink/confirmation code inside that:

```
$input_lines = file_get_contents('https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1C25uoL6nIqqNhex3wm8VwODsO2q2pXBt&export=download');
preg_match_all("/confirm=([0-9A-Za-z]+)&/", $input_lines, $output_array);
$hotlink = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm='.$output_array[1][0].'&id=1C25uoL6nIqqNhex3wm8VwODsO2q2pXBt
```

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the confirm code or is it secret google business?

Comment: I didn't investigate any further since March. It could be random, could be a trade secret or it could just as well be some simple checksum. Just fetch the virus scan page first and get the direct link from there using the snippet posted in the answer.

Comment: Ok thank you! Can that exact thing be done in JavaScript/jQuery as well? Do you know how?

Comment: sure:
`let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = () => {
 if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
           let token = xhr.responseText.match("/confirm=([0-9A-Za-z]+)&/");
           window.location.replace('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=' + token[1] + '&id=1C25uoL6nIqqNhex3wm8VwODsO2q2pXBt');
        }
    }
} 
xhr.open("GET", 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1C25uoL6nIqqNhex3wm8VwODsO2q2pXBt&export=download');`

Comment: Untested, but I think you can get the general idea from that snippet.

i.e. send xhr request to av check site, regex search for the direct link on said page, redirect to new url with direct link token inside.

Comment: Awesome. I'll test it and get back! Thanks!!

Comment: I get `unexpected token: name (xhr)`. And a `js parse error get eval`. Do you know what that is? //edit. ok, I ran it through Babel. Trying it out :)

Comment: I opened a new thread here. Feel free to check it out. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53026080/by-pass-virus-scan-for-google-drive-links-and-get-the-confirm-id

Comment: Wow, when I thought I was about to crack this one. Now all the gdrive files goes directly to download with the confirm code, not playing back in the browser. Doesn't want to stream. Did they change anything?!

Comment: Looksl ike it. It was still working when I posted my comment last week.

Comment: Ok bummer! Thanks

Comment: Hi I was trying to do this with PHP but whenever I actually go to the link, the confirm code resets and I'm just redirected to the virus threat page again. Once you have the  link, how do you actually get to the file itself?

Comment: Apparently the link expires after some time. At least that's how it seems to work for me. I can grab a hotlink and enter it in several different browsers, but the old one I posted here is redirecting to the cannot be scanned page.