# By-pass virus scan for Google Drive links and get the confirm ID

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

With some help from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522483/php-script-to-generate-direct-links-of-google-drive-files-skipping-virus-scan-wa/49523486?noredirect=1#comment92936322_49523486) I came up with the code below. How can I fetch the Google Drive file ID, open the direct link to the file and snatch the virus scan confirm ID that is required to stream files over 100 MB and then puzzle back the link? I'm kind of stuck at the xhr part.

```js
function fixGoogleDriveURL(url) {
  if (url.indexOf('drive.google.com') !== -1) {
    var DocIDfull = url;
    var DocIDstart = DocIDfull.indexOf('open?id=');
    if (DocIDstart == -1) {
      // invalid
      return url;
    }
    var DocID = DocIDfull.slice(DocIDstart+8);
    url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + DocID;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          var token = xhr.responseText.match("/confirm=([0-9A-Za-z]+)&/");
          window.location.replace(url + '&confirm=' + token[1]);
          // should I add url += '&confirm=' + token[1] here instead of window.location?
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();
  }
  return url;
}
console.log(fixGoogleDriveURL('https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C25uoL6nIqqNhex3wm8VwODsO2q2pXBt') + "\n<-- should output:\nhttps://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1C25uoL6nIqqNhex3wm8VwODsO2q2pXBt&confirm=XXXXX");
```

Comment: Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I tried adding `xhr.send()` and I do get the error `CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing`. Any way around it? Also it seems like it doesn't even go inside the `xhr.onload` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scraping GDrive using Client-Side JavaScript isn't explicitly allowed by Google and therefore your Ajax call/XHR fails.

The only way to get around that restriction is by using a proxy in the middle that will forward Google's Website code but add appropriate Access-Control Allow-Origin Headers.
You can either use your own server for that (some minimal server-side script code will do) or you can use a service like http://multiverso.me/AllOrigins/ or https://corsproxy.github.io/ to proxy the request for you.

The AllOrigins site has some example code for use with jQuery, but basically they work by URI encoding the URL you want to access and appending that string to the site's proxy URL.
Here's an article by freecodecamp.org that outlines how to use these services (skip to the `Don’t Let CORS Stop You!` section.

Note: A security advice: These services are working fine right now, but they could go out of business tomorrow and start serving malicious data instead or redirect your file requests to completely different files or completely different websites altogether. It's up to you to decide if you want to trust these strangers or not.

Comment: Thank you! However it seems like I no longer can stream videos from gdrive even with the confirm code. I just get a popup about downloading the file, can't play it in the browser. That must have changed recently. Or can you get this file to play in the browser? https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=CfLW&id=1C25uoL6nIqqNhex3wm8VwODsO2q2pXBt

Comment: Looks like it, yes. Seems like they changed it at some point last week.

Comment: Haha damn. Ok. So I guess I’m screwed? :)

Comment: Could be related to renaming Google Drive to Google 1. At least for Germany that should happen today and when Google announces these things it usually means it's happening over the course of a few days until everyone is in.